# How do I create a statically linked executable file with MSVC?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have c++ code that I want to compile with cl.exe, but I want it as a single exe file with that contains within itself all of the dll's it uses.

I tried using /MT option - "Creates a multithreaded DLL using MSVCRT.lib."

It did compile, however I can see it produces "Load Image" events (using Procmon), which means (maybe i'm wrong) that is not statically linked.

[image]

Is /MT the right option? If not, what is the right option?

Comment: "Is /MT the right option?" - No.

Comment: See edit please.